# Google analytics api Get the userID / ClientID

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-apis-explorer

I want to get the usage data of my customer out of google analytics, to make some usability analysis with it. For this, I need something that I can determine, which event was done by which user. Is there a possibility in a google analytics api to get this two parts linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a user ID as a custom dimension, you'd probably want to set the scope to user. 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

This would allow you to connect up which users performed which actions.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can! :) I have used it in a lot of projects.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits

Example:

```
  ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Video',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'cats.mp4'
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast question. Yes of course, but I need this data back from google analytics to my system, in a similar way! Is this also possibly over an api?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/ Like this?

Comment: Yes, but there I can find the user metrics:
- userType 
- activeUser 

and the event metrics: 
action, category and lable

but there is no userID or something else to connect this two things!?

Answer (score 0):

Since clientId has been made available through the API as ga:clientId you can use this value.
I would recommend using a custom User Id though - setting you own generated User Id in the script using the Universal Analytics User ID feature and in your backend db.

Also add the id to any link you send to your clients via email/sms/etc. that lands on your homepage to follow up on marketing performance.
You would need to have some javascript that grab the id and set it on the pageview. (like Linker, but adjusted for user id)

Note to anyone using the Universal Analytics User ID feature The values returned in ga:clientId is actually the userId Even more interessting. (As of time of writing) GA fails if you request clientId from a User ID view. So you should use a non-User ID view to get the User ID. :)